# How to filter/remove select list values for specific operator and vice versa in react-awesome-query-builder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{
 "type": "select"
 "operators": [ "select_equals", "select_not_equals"],
 "listValues": { "1": "abc", "2": "def", "3": "ghi"}
}
```

Is it possible when the user selects the "equal" operator then only shows "abc, def" value in SelectWidget options, "ghi" option only shown when the user selects "not equal" operator and this behavior should work vice versa also, means if user select "ghi" options then he/she should not able to see "equal" operator?

Comment: just look at `Array.filter` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter